# Fixing helmet padding

Tags: repair, helmets

I was trying to remove the helmet padding to wash it and the two layers separated. [image: Helmet padding split]

Instead of replacing the helmet which is wastful, can anyone suggest ways (non-toxic glue?) of repairing the padding?

Comment: There is a type of (usually) clear silicone based adhesive used for crafts and children's artwork. It is mostly odorless, dries in about an hour. Non water soluble once dried. It is non destructive on foam and may give good results on fabric too. I do not know a generic name for all countries, but here it is sold as "UHU universal glue" and other brands too. The little bottle I have now says "Liquid silicon".

Comment: Depending on the maker of the helmet, some sell replacement padding.

Comment: @Carel indeed. There are also "generic" pads available. Many helmets have little patches of hook side of hook and loop (a.k.a. velcro) that make the generic pads stay in place. The ones I have used do not have the specific shape but close enough. I have also made my own replacement out of "foamy" (from the arts and crafts store). Not as comfy but lasted longer than the commercially available ones.

Comment: @Jahaziel The adhesive used for children's artwork is usually [PVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyvinyl_acetate) glue. Could you identify the UHU product you're referring to from their [products page](https://www.uhu.com/en/product-overview)? Some of them contain solvents which will attack plastics.

Comment: Be also aware that glue may possibly dissolve PE foam (helmet material) quite dramatically fast.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's difficult for me as in my country many products are not available, the brands offer different lineups or the labeling is not a literal translation (Spanish spoken) However, these glues usually state being safe for styrofoam, which is pretty much helmet material. However, from the linked page, the one labelled "ALL PURPOSE ADHESIVE SOLVENT FREE" seems to be the most similar the what i'd use. Craft stores usually sell small styrofoam shapes. Buy a couple and test the glue before using it in your helmet.

Comment: (Continued) PVA glue is "wood glue". It would be perfect for cardboard, paper, wood sticks and most non plastic materials, but It wouldn't bond "foamy" nor fabric to fabric. It's also white when in the bottle (We call it "white glue" here) and it's water soluble, it dries translucent. The Silicone glue I'm referring to is transparent in the bottle, dries transparent and flexible, is not water soluble (its easier to peel off hands) and It bonds materials like foamy well enough to withstand water play.

Comment: @Jahaziel I have PVA "fabric glue" as well as PVA "craft glue" and wood glue.  It sticks fabric, including foam, very well, but doesn't handle damp conditions (it's annoying because there are waterproof PVA wood glues)

Comment: Good point @Carel.  I assumed you'd take the pads away from the helmet to repair, and not put them back in until fully dried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a needle and some thread to sew the two layers together in a couple of spots. I'd reinforce all the other sections too like this, if the factory adhesive is prone to coming undone.

Comment: Agreed - a glue tends to have thickness or texture when cured, which interferes with the padding function of the foam.   Additionally some glues react badly with skin even when cured, and the moist area of one's eyeball is heavily affected by glue fumes for multiple days.   Personally I'd go with a sewing machine, but only because I have one.  Hand sewing is slow and results in larger stitches.

Comment: Another option is for OP to cut and sew a new "pillow-case" from suitable soft fabric for the existing foam, which has doubtless become thin and squashy over time.

Comment: That's how I fixed padding on my favorite helmet when the cloth layers started to split.

Answer (score 2):

I have had some success in the past with fabric glue.

You need to choose a solvent-based, rather than water-based, glue, and try to avoid having the glue come out at the edges, as it can be rather scratchy when dried.  To protect the rest of the helmet, take the pads out for repair, and don't fit them until the glue has fully dried.

It will fail again eventually, but by that time the helmet tends to be getting past its best.